# Cygwin script fails arithmetic expression

Tags: math, cygwin

Source:
`

```
#!/bin/bash

in=$1

off=3

while true;
do

#echo $i

off1=$(( $off - 1 ))

declare -A a=0
declare -A b=0
declare -A x=0

a=$(head -n $off $in | tail -n 1)
b=$(head -n $off1 $in | tail -n 1)



x=`expr $a - $b`
echo $a
echo $b
echo $x
echo $off1 $off
off=$(( $off + 1 ))

done
```

`

Output:
`

```
./seq /bin/sequence.txt
expr: non-integer argument
9121600
9082152

2 3
expr: non-integer argument
9219455
9121600

3 4
expr: non-integer argument
9275501
9219455
```

etc
`
Script is supposed to echo xyz coordinates for phase space analysis.

I have tried expressing the subtraction with $(( $a - $b )) as well... similar error.
Any clues?

Answer (score 0):

This is not Cygwin specific.  In bash, `declare -A` creates an associative array, on which arithmetic is obviously invalid.  Perhaps you meant to use `declare -i` instead?

Comment: Thank you... that may be the case but I discovered the issue was in the file with dos carriage return lines.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered the issue was in the file with dos carriage return lines.